# Is it possible to create bitmap image with one bit per pixel?

Tags: bitmap

I need to create a image where 0 is coded as nothing and 1 as obstacle and send it over socket in c.

The solution I found is to use bitmap to use RLE coding (to reduce the datas over the socket). But the thing is that I haven't found any article that explain how to deal with one bit per pixel.

Is it possible ? I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Sure this is possible, it's been done very often in earlier times (when memory was expensive and displays where black + white).

Comment: Do I need to implement the coding  myself or do you know some sources ?

Comment: I know some libraries that would work for me, but these are not in C. Suggesting libraries is off-topic here, so I won't even try. You might want to look around on github or similar sites.